# Migrate from Bind mount to Volumes using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

newbie in docker here

With the objective of get unified backups of containers data, i want to migrate all existing containers that have Bind mounts to Volumes using docker-compose.

Following this simple reddit reply: https://www.reddit.com/r/selfhosted/comments/hkoe2u/correct_way_to_move_dockercompose_container_from/

But Grafana not catch the configuration.

Trying to migrate a Grafana (first of all, and for example) container, here is the docker-compose.yml

```
`version: "2"

services:
  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
      #- ./grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      #- ./grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
      - g_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - g_provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    #restart: unless-stopped
    restart: always
      # get from host system, "id -u" was running as root so user is "0"
    user: '0'
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

volumes:
  g_data:
  g_provisioning:
```

`
Is a permission issue? or What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you brought the container down and up again? How do you determine that it doesn't use the volume?

Comment: Yes, i stop/start the container. I think that the container is not using the volume because is Grafana ask for admin user for the first time. How do you check that the container is using the volume? Thanks

Comment: The volume is empty, so shouldn't it as for admin user?

Comment: The volume is not empty, contain all bind mount data, copied from: "./grafana_data" to "Mountpoint: "/var/lib/docker/volumes/grafana_g_data/_data" " Thanks

Comment: How did you copy the data into the volume?

Comment: Just use cp -R command. How should i do it?

Comment: Hi again, if someone is there. I can verify that the container is linked to the volumes
`code
$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' 9cfb6bb6750e
[{volume grafana_g_provisioning /var/lib/docker/volumes/grafana_g_provisioning/_data /etc/grafana/provisioning local rw true } {volume grafana_g_data /var/lib/docker/volumes/grafana_g_data/_data /var/lib/grafana local rw true }] code`.
How can i check that the volume is sharing files with the app ?